# Can someone explain this DROP TABLE command? What am I missing?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

```
USE AP; 
IF OBJECT_ID('spCopyInvoices') IS NOT NULL
     DROP PROC spCopyInvoices;
GO

CREATE PROC spCopyInvoices 
AS
     IF OBJECT_ID('InvoiceCopy') IS NOT NULL 
          DROP TABLE InvoiceCopy;
     SELECT * 
     INTO InvoiceCopy 
     FROM Invoices;
```

The text says it copies a table but I'm reading it that if the object (either spCopyInvoices or InvoiceCopy) has data (is not null), then drop it. So how does that work? What am I missing?

Comment: This script will CREATE a stored procedure (not execute it).   If the SP already exists ... delete it.    The stored procedure (once executed) will DROP InvoiceCopy if it already exists, and then create a new table InvoiceCopy from Invoices

Answer (score 1):

"What am I missing?" -- That the code following the `DROP TABLE InvoiceCopy`,

```
...
SELECT * 
INTO InvoiceCopy 
FROM Invoices;
...
```

creates a table `InvoiceCopy` filled with the contents of the table `Invoice`. I.e. the procedure, when called, sort of makes a copy of `Invoice` called `InvoiceCopy`. That's what the "text" you refer to wants to say very likely. It describes what the procedure does that is created in the code snippet.

That "the object" is dropped when it "has data" isn't quit right either. It is dropped, when it *exists*. In both instances. (But one could argue that a procedure cannot have data anyway.)

Answer (score 0):

DROP TABLE deletes the table. Suppose, in SQL I write,

```
    CREATE TABLE "Hello, World" IF NOT EXISTS; /*It makes a table if it is not there in the database. */
     DROP TABLE "Hello, World"; /*It just deletes the stuff (or tables) that we just created..*/
```